# No horizontal scroll bar for min width of page

Tags: css, html, scrollbar

Website: http://www.animefushigi.com

Make your browser window skinny, note that there is no horizontal scroll bar, there should be one if your browser window is skinnier than 1024 px width.

```
<div id="master_wrapper"><div id="outer_wrapper">
   ..
</div></div>

#master_wrapper {
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#outer_wrapper {
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-top:87px
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you don't get a scrollbar is because you have `overflow: hidden` on the outer two `div`s. Unfortunately, removing the `overflow: hidden`s will cause problems. Instead, add:

```
body {
    min-width: 1024px
}
```

That will force a scrollbar.